# Как сделать рассылку в Телеграм C#? Telegram.Bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Делаю функцию рассылки вот так:

```
string mailing = messageText;
if (messageText == "/mailing" && userId == 22222222)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT userId FROM [Users]";
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new string[1]);
                    data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
                foreach (string[] s in data)
                {
                    Message message = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: s[0].ToString(),
                    text: mailing,
                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            }
```

Рассылка работает, но не так как хотелось... Я не могу получить в переменную `mailing` текст который я хочу опубликовать так как текст обновляется и выводиться /mailing.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так:

```
if (messageText.Split(' ').First() == "/mailing" && userId == 2222222)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT userId FROM [Users]";
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new string[1]);
                    data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
                foreach (string[] s in data)
                {
                    Message message = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: s[0].ToString(),
                    text: messageText.Substring(9),
                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
```